# Weebly Navigation - Parent Menu Item Stays in hover when mouse on child item

Tags: html, css, hover, nav

So, I am a beginner on CSS and HTML, and I am trying from the past hour for this to work, but it just wont!

So I want the parent menu item to stay hovered when mouse goes over the child of that parent in the dropdown menu.

Here is my code..

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body class='short-header-page  wsite-theme-light'>

        <div id="header-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <table id="header">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="header-right">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="phone-number">{phone:text}</td>
                                    <td class="social">{social}</td>
                                    <td class="search">{search}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div><!-- end container -->
        </div><!-- end header-wrap -->          

        <div id="nav-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="logo">{logo}</td>
                        <td id="nav"><div id="navigation">{menu}</div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div><!-- end container -->
        </div><!-- end nav-wrap -->

        <div id="banner-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="banner">
                        <div class="wsite-header"></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div><!-- end banner -->
            </div><!-- end container -->
        </div><!-- end banner-wrap -->

        <div id="main-wrap">
            <div class="container">
                {content}
            </div><!-- end container -->
        </div><!-- end main-wrap -->

    <div id="footer-wrap">
        <div style="visibility:hidden;"class="container">
            {footer}
        </div><!-- end container -->
    </div><!-- end footer-wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#nav-wrap .container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom:1px solid #E8E8E8;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

#nav-wrap .container table, #nav-wrap .container table tr, #nav-wrap .container table tr td, #nav-wrap .container table tbody {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

td#nav {
    float:right;
}
#navigation {
    line-height: 1;
    float: right;
}

#navigation ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    max-width:700px;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}

#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left:6px;
    float: left;
}

#navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 18px 7px 8px;
    margin:0 0px 1px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float: left;
    font:13px 'Bookman',arial,sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#navigation ul li#active a{
    padding: 18px 7px 4px;
    border-bottom:4px solid #72bc11;
    color:#000;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover {
    padding: 18px 7px 4px;
    border-bottom:4px solid #FF6600;
    color: #000A0F;
}
#navigation ul li a:hover {
    padding: 18px 7px 4px;
    border-bottom:4px solid #FF6600;
    color: #000A0F;
}
/* Navigation Submenu's
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu {
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
}


#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
    background: #F4F4F4;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    display: block;
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
    color: #72bc11;
    background: #eee;
}
```

Can you help me guys? Please I am desparate I dont know how to make this work! :/

Comment: Your CSS show navigation tags for `ul` and `li` tags yet your html has none.  This looks to be some type of word press  or similar document.  When you have {} appearing within html elements, specifically `{menu}`, it usually denotes some type of markup that is replaced by the governing architecture. Which means the navigation is injected on the page when viewed in a browser.  There is nothing to work with here

Comment: you need to view the page that has the rendered menu and view the source in a browser. Then you can copy/paste the relevant portion of the Navigation

Comment: You are on the wrong track with all those tables. Here's a simple dropdown example that you could use: http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/dropdown_horizontal2.htm (Just view source to get the code.)

Comment: Well, weebly is proven not to be that customizable. I am gonna grab the complete code from my site and add it separated - be able to edit it. Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu: hover #navigation ul li a {
    color: #333;
}
```